# how to create a barcode of an employee ID card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

gemfile consists of `gem 'barby'`

I have written a code in my controller:

```
require 'barby'    
require 'barby/barcode/ean_13'    
require 'barby/outputter/ascii_outputter'    
require 'barby/outputter/html_outputter'

def show
  @card = Barby::EAN13.new(emp_code)
  @card_for_html = Barby::HtmlOutputter.new(@card)
end

private
  def emp_code
    @emp_code = "#{@user.date_of_joining} + #{@user.full_name} + #{@user.id}"
  end
```

In my view I have written:

```
<%@card.ascii=@card.to_ascii%> </p>    
<%=raw @card_path_for_html.to_html%>   </p>
```

Which produces the error `undefined method 'to_ascii'`

Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: did you try `@card= Barby::Code128B.new(emp_code)`

`puts @card.to_ascii`

Comment: I am writing code with EAN13

Comment: yes I know I say did you try ? what is `emp_code` ? is it only throwing error for EAN13 that I have to know

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Comment: go to `rails console` and try `@card= Barby::Code128B.new(1234)` `puts @card.to_ascii`

Comment: emp_code I have defined in private.

Comment: undefined method `code128B' for Barby:Module

Comment: did you    `require 'barby' require 'barby/barcode/code_128' require 'barby/outputter/ascii_outputter'` then `@card= Barby::Code128B.new(1234)` and `puts @card.to_ascii`

Comment: its code_128 or code_128B?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to create a barcode